# Need some help having this work the way i need

Tags: php, redirect

ok so I just launched a new website and I have a bit of an issue with redirection. htaccess redirects don't like handling the values in a php url and push them to the new one and soIi got this but I need a little help

redirect plugins for wordpress
cpanel
making my own

```
<?php

$redirect[0] = 'http://url-1.com';
$redirect[1] = 'http://url-2.com';
$redirect[2] = 'http://url-3.com';

$number = mt_rand(0,2);

header("Location:$redirect[$number]");

?>
```

i need this to be able to work like this

Page.php?redirect=name
to redirect to a url

I know I'm damn close but how to i make it the proper name and request?
all the old site urls are
`article.php?articlelist=bobdo_14_ol`
or `article.php?articlelist=taco_23_tt`
etc

I'm trying to make them redirect but it's beyond my skill range

Comment: Hey, since its a wordpress plugin you are looking for, you should consult the wordpress plugin directory there are many plugins for that. The other Think you trying to look for would be $_GET Variables and their usage

Comment: im not looking for a plugin, i said i tried a wordpress plugin. but am trying to make my own php file to put in place instead. no need for more possibly vulnerable plugins anyway

Comment: im assuming something like this may work?

    $var = $_GET['article'];
    
    if($var == 'one'){
        header("Location: http://www.one.com/");
    }else if ($var == 'two'){
        header("Location: http://www.two.com/");
    }

Answer (score 0):

this code worked great
thanks for the idea on get values

```
$var = $_GET['article'];

if($var == 'one'){
    header("Location: http://www.one.com/");
}else if ($var == 'two'){
    header("Location: http://www.two.com/");
}
```